# React native how can parent to pass a function to the child

Tags: react-native, parent-child, navigator

In react native, If want the child to call parent's function, i can do the following:

In parent:

```
<Child myFunc={this.handleChildFunc.bind(this)} />
```

And the child would call that function like so:

```
onpress=this.props.myFunc();
```

How can I achieve this in Navigator and NavigatorIOS through passProps?

```
<NavigatorIOS
    initialRoute={{
      component: MyScene,
      title: 'My Initial Scene',
      passProps: { myProp: this.handleChildFunc.bind(this) }  // Not work
      passProps: { myProp: ()=>this.handleChildFunc.bind(this) }  //Not work
    }}
    style={{flex: 1}}
  />
```

Update

Thanks For reply, but i'm new to react native, not really understand how to implement below answer in navigatorIOS. However, I tried the following and the child can success calling parent's function

In parent, pass callback as props

```
passProps: { parentFunc: ()=>this.handleFunc() }
```

In child

```
this.props.handleFunc();
```

Answer (score 3):

This code work for me

```
return(
    <NavigatorIOS
        initialRoute={{
          component: MyScene,
          title: 'My Initial Scene',
          myProp: (() => { this.handleChildFunc.bind(this) }) // work
        }}
        renderScene={ (route, navigator) =>
          <Child navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} onFun={ route.myProp } /> 
        }
      />
)
```

When call in child

```
this.props.onFun()
```

[Check here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [demo](https://github.com/CoderGLM/ReactNativeLeaning/tree/master/2.4NavigatorTest), maybe helpful.

Example of the renderScene function:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
  let Component = route.component;
  return <Component {...route.params} navigator={navigator} />
}
```

Example of the pushing a new scene:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  component: Child,
  func: customFunc
})
```

then you can use `this.props.func` in Child page(the secondary page).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.